# c++ Calling class method inside same method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I´m writing the clsLog class:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <time.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "clsLog.h"


std::string     m_strCurLogUser; 
int         m_iCurLogAction;        
int         m_iCurLogLevel;     
std::ofstream           m_oCurLogFile;

// 
// LogInit
// Initilize the log parameters of the system.
// The FileName will be the file name that the system will log the messages (LOG.TXT is the default if no names are given).
// The DatabaseName and TableName specifies the database and table name to be used for log. The default is "LOG_DATABASE" and "LOG_TABLE"
// will be done.
// The Action shall be an OR with all the options. Att: If an option is giver (ex: Database) and an invalid name is given, then an error will occur.
//
// The default log level is zero (0). So every log with a level upper than that will be logged. A change to the level must be done 
// using the SetLogLevel method.
//
// return = 0: Success
//      1: Failure
//
int LogInit (std::string FileName,      // Initialize the log file/connection.
             std::string DatabaseName,  // Database name to connect to.
             std::string TableName,     // Table name to connect to.
             std::string UserName,      // User name to log into
             int Action)                // Action to be done.
{
    //
    // If the file is already open, someone is calling that function before closing the previous one. Error.
    //
    if (m_oCurLogFile.is_open ())
    {
        std::string msg;

        msg = "LogInit called for " + FileName + " witout closing previous session. Error";
        this->clsLog::Log (msg);
    }

        // Do some stuff

    return 0;
}

// 
// Log
// Logs the Message according to its Level.
//
// return = 0: Success
//          1: Failure
//
int Log (std::string Message, int Level) // Register a log according to the log state.
{
    time_t now;
    struct tm ptm;
    char buffer [32];

    //
    // If the sent message level is below the current level, abort.
    //
    if (Level < m_iCurLogLevel)
        return 1;


    // Get the current date and time and convert it to the time structure (ptm)
    now = time (NULL);
    localtime_s (&ptm, &now);

    //
    // Format the time structure: DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:SS)
    strftime (buffer, 32, "%D/%M/%Y %H:%M:%S", &ptm);


    // Check if needs to be logged on stdio
    //
    if ((m_iCurLogLevel & LOGACTION_STDOUT) == LOGACTION_STDOUT)
    {
        cout << buffer + " " + Message; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I´m not being able to compile. I´m getting the following error at

```
this->clsLog::Log (msg);
```

C2227 error on left of '->Log' must point to a class/struct/union/generic type. Using VS2010, Win32 application.

Help appreciated.

Rds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any evidence that your functions are inside a class definition; therefore, as the error message says, there's no "this" pointer available.  "This" is only available in the instance members of a class.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` pointer is only valid inside a method that is a (non-static) member of a class or struct.  There is no `this` for a plain function such as `LogInit`.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do of course. ;-)  I don't have the code for clsLog so I don't actually know what you're doing.  Did you try just removing the `this->`?  Perhaps `clsLog::Log()` is a static method and it'll just work.  Otherwise, go look at the `clsLog.h` header file to understand how to use it.

Comment: Probably `int clsLog::LogInit`

Comment: Forgot the class clsLog at the beginning of the file. Very basic. Thanks for help.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please consider marking an answer as accepted if it helped answer your question as that will help the next person with a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the "accept" button. I did it now and surely I will do it next time.